# Android webview scroll down when soft keyboard is activated

Tags: android, keyboard, webview

I have searched about all the post but I can't found the solution on my problem.
In my application I have some webview; when the edit text are clicked the webview page scroll down and is it not possible to see the  inserted text.
I try the solution of android:windowSoftInputMode="AdjustPan" but he didn't worked.

There are another particular aspect, when in the same webview I load some pages the scrolling working correctly, but in other I have the above situation.

Is it possible that there are  problems in html/css code of the load pages?

Thanks and Regards
Simone

Comment: There isn't anyone that can help me??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I have found the solution.
What that had caused the problem was that in my layout.xml I put the webview into a scrollview block.
The removal of scrollview block resolve my problem.
I hope that the solution can be useful for someone.

Comment: Thanks. I've been trying to figure out what the cause of this issue has been for quite a while.